# Number of solutions to square root equation

Tags: number-theory

Find the number of distinct pairs of integers $(x, y)$ such that $0 < x < y$ and $\sqrt{1984} = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}.$

I know that $\sqrt{1984}=8\sqrt{31}$, but am not sure how to use it.  Could I get a bit of help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Good starting point! You have reduced the problem to:
Find the number of ... and $8=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  We have
$$\sqrt{1984}-\sqrt x=\sqrt y\ ;$$
squaring both sides gives
$$16\sqrt{31x}=1984+x-y\ ;$$
but the RHS is an integer, so $x$ must be $31$ times a square, say $x=31a^2$ where $a$ is a positive integer.  Now do something similar for $y$; substitute back into your given equation; and you should find the rest is easy.